# Creating an Ajax timer in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, timer

I'm trying to figure out the best solution to create a "game-round" timer in Ruby/Rails. Right now I'm just jotting notes, but in theory I'd like to set a 30 second timer on each round of game activity. Once the timer hits 0, the users turn is over.

On Ruby's end, I know I can accomplish this with a while loop and sleep(30), or some combination of the Timer class.

However, i'm getting stumped trying to design the best way to *show the user* their time left on the clock. Use Ajax? periodiocally_call_remote? What should I query for?

Just thinking out loud, figured I'd ask the crowd.

Comment: A bit more description... I'd like to show the user a "countdown" of time left on the clock. Which would possibly mean using Ajax to update a div "live". Yet... beyond just showing them a countdown, once the user takes action (or doesn't before the round is over)... I'd like a method to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a [javascript timer](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).  When the countdown is over, call your end_turn() method.

I wouldn't want to hit the server every second just for a countdown.  You can do it all client-side and only hit the server when the turn is over (or a move is made)

Comment: Good Suggestion, that's what i was worried about... polling too much. But keeping it completely client side and running a method at the end of the timer should work fine. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `periodiocally_call_remote`. I don't know if this will cause issues with Internet Explorer 6 or not.